# Jenkins Pipeline script - return value of a build step

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is there a way to fetch URL of a build step (without waiting for completion) through Jenkins pipeline script?

Here is what I've tried but the return value of build is `null`.

`def build_job = build job: 'dummy_job', wait: false`

Trying to fetch URL as follows:
`build_job.absoluteUrl`

Answer (score 5):

You can get it by using the getRawBuild() method:

```
   def build_job=build(job:'dummy_job',propagate:false)
   echo build_job.getResult()
   echo build_job.getRawBuild().getAbsoluteUrl()
```

Don't use `wait: false` since the function won't return the expected result.
`propagate: false` is so that the current job won't abort (fail before the next step) if the called job fails.

Comment: I couldn't find build_job.getRawBuild().getAbsoluteUrl(), but using build_job.getAbsoluteUrl() directly gives me the URL okay.

Answer (score -2):

`BUILD_URL` should provide you the job url. You can get all environment variables in the pipeline using `env` bash command.

Jenkins doc: [here](https://qa.nuxeo.org/jenkins/pipeline-syntax/globals)

Comment: This is true about the current running job, but not for a job you trigger from it